# Where can I ask questions about payment gateways or implementing billing myself?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions, scope

I just moved to Brazil and I'm in the process of starting a new company. I'm having difficulty finding a payment gateway that offers a cost-efficient, integrated solution with monthly recurrent billing. I narrowed my scope to two questions:

> 1. How can I safely store credit card info and bill my customers manually via a machine (as a restaurant would do, for example)?

This is a programming related question that can be asked on SO. It is, however, also my last resort, and I am more interested in the following question:

> 2. Can anyone advise me on finding a payment gateway that can fulfill my specific needs?

I am unsure of where to ask this question.

In my view both questions are related and I would prefer to post them together. While the first part is about programming, the second, which is more crucial to me, has nothing to do with programming.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, a post that starts with "Can anyone advise me" is not going to be appropriate for any Stack Exchange site. We focus on questions that can be answered here, and although your issue is valid, it's not really a question.

For your first question, you might try the [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site; not sure how well it'll be received either there or on SO, though.

Comment: Well, both questions might easily fit 'good subjective' definition, if worded appropriately.

Comment: The first question might be OK, but the 2nd probably not (too localised).

Comment: @ChrisF, hence my issue. I really would rather not store anyone's information. But I might have to if I have another choice. Another choice may exist, but I SO doesn't provide a site for such a question. Even though SO users have a wealth of knowledge that can actually answer my question.